# delayed_job rake task parameters and concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

The [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) states that a delayed job worker can be invoked using a rake task like so: `rake jobs:work`, or `QUEUE=queue1 rake jobs:work` if you want it to work on a specific queue.

I have a couple of questions about this way to invoke jobs:

1. Is there a way to pass other parameters like `sleep-delay` or `read-ahead` (like you would do if you start the worker using the script: `delayed_job start --sleep-delay 30 --read-ahead 500 --queue=queue1`)?
2. Is there any gain in processing speed if you launch 2 workers on the same queue using the rake task?

Comment: A point of interest and possibly relevant to the answer, why do you need this?

Comment: Does https://github.com/zxiest/delayed_job_active_record_threaded do it for you? disclaimer: I built this gem.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to 1. - yes you can set sleep delay and read ahead from the command line. You do it via environment variables:

```
QUEUE=queue1 SLEEP_DELAY=1 rake jobs:work
```

for example. See [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/110f0e22784af620068b613557e907af5e0e359f) commit.

Answer (score 0):

`rake jobs:work` is just a means to an end to put up another worker, for development purposes or to work off a big queue (you have `rake jobs:workoff` for this though) so all benefits and disclaimers of multiple workers apply,

two jobs process in parallel so if you've got the cpu power your queue will be worked quicker

I don't know about the question `#1` though, it's possible `rake jobs` wasn't intended to be used outside of development